# Breaks from loop

Tags: java

first, I have validated my code so it keeps repeating until a "yes" or a "no" is given when being asked "Continue?". But my code breaks from the loop after entering a random value and then yes.
for example:

```
Add or delete another name? Add
Please enter a name you want to add: Matt
Continue? f
Continue? yes
```

It should say:

```
Add or delete another name? Add
Please enter a name you want to add: Matt
Continue? f
Continue? yes
Add or delete another name?
```

actual code

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class AddOrDeleteNames {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("names.txt"));
    Scanner myScan = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner scanRedo = new Scanner(System.in);
    String userRedo;
    String userResponse;

    while (scan.hasNext())
        names.add(scan.next());

    do {    
      System.out.print("Add or delete another name? ");
      userResponse = myScan.next();

      if (userResponse.equalsIgnoreCase("add")) {
        System.out.print("Please enter a name you want to add: ");
        names.add(myScan.next());
      } else if (userResponse.equalsIgnoreCase("delete")) {
        System.out.print("Please enter a name you want to delete: ");
        names.remove(myScan.next());
      } else {
        System.out.print("Invalid Choice");
      }

      PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("namesupdated.txt");
      for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++)
        writer.println(names.get(i));

      writer.close();

      System.out.print("Continue? ");
      userRedo = scanRedo.next();
    } while (userRedo.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"));

    do {
        if(userRedo.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
            System.out.print("Thank You.");
            userRedo = scanRedo.next();
        } else if (!userRedo.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
            System.out.print("Continue? ");  // LOOP ENDS EARLY : FIX!
            userRedo = scanRedo.next();
        }
    } while (!userRedo.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")); 

    scan.close();
    myScan.close();
    scanRedo.close();
}
```

}

Comment: Please use a debugger for this kind of issues, then make a question if you don't understand something.

Comment: Where's that "Continue" coming from?

Comment: First thing I did is I searched for the part of your code where the word "Continue" is printed.  I figured that your problem might be in the proximity of that part of the code.  I hit `ctrl+f` and typed `continue` in the search box, and didn't find that part of the code.  That's when I lost patience with the question

Comment: @SamIam sorry, have updated

Comment: Well, I don't know why you think, that your second loop ends early. You write "yes" and it will only loop again if you're writing something else than "yes".

Comment: 2 loop asking to continue, bad condition to stop looping. Use a debugger fo this kind of question

Comment: I don't know what other users saw when this was posted, but there is no question here now. (presumably due to edit by original poster)

Comment: @JonKiparsky You can open the "edit history" and see the old versions of a question/answer if you click on the `edited x mins ago` link that can be found beneath the post.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to continue when you write `"yes"` get rid of the `!` in

```
while (!userRedo.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"));
```

---

Secondly, you should probably put the entire block of code that you want to continue with in it's own do-while loop.

I'm only bringing this up because your second do-while loop won't output `Add or delete another name?` like your expected output would suggest.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
  ...
  else if (!userRedo.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
        {
            System.out.print("Continue? ");  // LOOP ENDS EARLY : FIX!
            userRedo = scanRedo.next();
        }
    }
    while (!userRedo.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"));
```

It enters the else-if clause when you answered "f".

Then it takes in a "yes" and overwrites userRedo. So, the while condition returns false and so the loop breaks.

Comment: Well, the problem is not in this code you've posted. The problem is, that the program can leave the first loop without requiring the corresponding user input.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, I didn't look it through well enough.

Java reads things top to bottom, left to right. What you did is deploy another `do...while` loop after the main one. So, after you say "yes" to continuing the second `do...while` loop stops executing and you close all your scanners.

```
do {
    if(userRedo.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
        System.out.print("Thank You.");
        userRedo = scanRedo.next();
    } else if (!userRedo.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
        System.out.print("Continue? ");  // LOOP ENDS EARLY : FIX!
        userRedo = scanRedo.next();
    }
} while (!userRedo.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")); 

scan.close();
myScan.close();
scanRedo.close();
```

}

After that you just close your class and the program assumes it has nothing left to do. Java only "goes back up" in it's reading if you call a separate method. So, for it to go back up and for you to keep both of your `do...while` loops you just need to put them in separate methods, calling them when the approved answer is given.

For example:

```
//Declare variables up here, it will make the entire class have access to them

public static void main(String[] args){
        loop();
    }
public static void loop(){
    //do...while here

    System.out.println("Continue?");
    check();
}
public static void check(){
    //Scanner.in()
    //do..while #2 here
    //User enters yes then:
    loop();
    //User enters no then:
    //whatever you want here
}
```

Comment: Check the edit, I answered your question, and pasted what the code would look like.

Comment: Why should the program ask again if the use already entered `"yes"`?

Comment: @NicholasEason I want it so that if the response is not yes, It repeats continue? and if its no, the program terminates

Comment: My bad, I completely edited my answer, hopefully this is the answer you were looking for.